# Новое значение слова

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Недавно услышала от знакомого, что он "опоздал на собаку". Оказалось, так называют электропоезд или электричку. Возможно, потому что это достаточно быстрый способ передвижения? Но при чём тут собака? Кто может объяснить, как и почему появилось это сленговое слово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это — не столько (не только) собака, сколько РЭКС. Аббревиатура от Регион-экспресса. Аэроэкспресс» провел ребрендинг подмосковных экспрессов: теперь (с 2011 г.) они синего цвета и имеют логотип, в основе которого — образ собаки.

Менеджеры проекта утверждают, что игра слов здесь вполне кстати, т. к. жители области и москвичи называют электрички собаками. Насколько это верно, не берусь судить, хотя как пассажир имею очень приличный стаж. Не слышал ни разу. Ни в доброжелательном контексте, ни в уничижительном.

Comment: Умничка, shampar! Спасибо Вам большое.

Answer (score 0):

"Собаками" с незапамятных времен именовали пригородные "рабочие" поезда. 
Медленные, некомфортные, для протонародьях.
"Рабочий" поезд, кстати, само по себе означает не технический поезд (с оборудованием для контроля состояния и ремонта путей - как для трамвая), а поезд **для** рабочих, без вагонов первого-второго класса. И разумеется, речь идет о тех временах, когда ни о каких РЭКСах слыхом не слыхивали.

Со временем такие рабочие поезда в большинстве своем были заменены электричками и отдали им свои названия. И "рабочий поезд" и "собака" это теперь электричка.
Среди футбольных болельщиков выражение "добирались на собаках" (на выездную игру) весьма популярно. При этом тратится много времени, необходимо несколько пересадок - ну в общем, весь набор удобств, но зато дешево.

Что же касается самого названия "собака", то скорее всего современная его популярность поддерживается ассоциацией с собачьей упряжкой (тот же набор "удовольствий"), а вот появление (в начале прошлого века, видимо) можно объяснить, например, собачьим отношением к пассажирам и подобными мотивами.

Вот несколько цитат, в той или иной степени подтверждающую сказанное

> Электричку называют собакой с советских времён. Началось всё с тех
>   электричек, на которых можно было добраться из Москвы в Петербург. На
>   перекладных, одну меняли на другую: сначала ехали до Твери, до Чудова,
>   а потом и до Петербурга. Получалось это по-студенчески дёшево, а
>   иногда без билетов и вообще бесплатно. То есть на электричке, как на
>   перекладных ездовых собаках, можно было перемещаться между двумя
>   городами. Почему именно собака, а не лошадь, ответа нет. Ни один мне
>   известный словарь жаргона не объясняет причины. Везде лишь написано,
>   что это молодёжный сленг 70-80-х годов.

http://www.the-village.ru/village/city/asking-question/131535-est-vopros
(если есть время посмотрите полный текст, там много, не только могу согласиться, что это 70 г. прошлого века, по мне так - гораздо раньше, еще до революции)

> - Собака - так некоторые люди называют пригородные электропоезда. По некоторым теориям, название произошло оттого, что электричка, подобно
>     собаке, останавливается у каждого столба. Однако, вероятнее, термин
>     'собака' возвращает нас в те времена, когда на севере ездили на
>     перекладных, меняя собачьи упряжки (как сейчас пересаживаются с одной
>     электрички на другую, направляясь в дальний путь) . Основное свойство
>     С. - они образуют непрерывную сеть на ж. д. России, и можно с
>     пересадками доехать куда угодно. Соответственно "собака с теткой", это
>     не "дама с собачкой", а пригородный поезд (дизель) по вагонам которого
>     курсирует тетя-билитер и громко вопрошает в каждом вагоне: "Все купили
>     билетики? " Бывает и "поезд за теткой" - типа есть проводник, но кроме
>     как за проверку билетов на входе, сей "проводник" ни за что не
>     отвечает.

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/38000118

> Есть мнение, что такое название произошло из-за того, что электричка 
>   останавливается у каждого столба, словно собака.
>
> Также считается, что термин «собака» появился в те времена, когда на
>   севере ездили на перекладных, меняя собачьи упряжки (сегодня же
>   пересаживаются с одного поезда на другой, что бы добраться до
>   какого-нибудь далекого города или населенного пункта).
>
> согласно третьей версии, электрички получили такое прозвище из-за того,
>   что первые железно-дорожные вагоны сильно скрипели и «визжали
>   как собаки».
>
> Наконец, четвертое мнение — потому, что пассажиров в вагон набивается, как 
>   блох на собаке.

http://pochemu.su/pochemu-elektrichku-nazyvayut-sobakoj/